# Refactor code to work with jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery

I found this jfiddle from another post on here.

Original: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTF5J/2/

With 1.9 and my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/4423c/

Looks like `.live()` is no longer supported with Jquery 1.9. I managed to modify a portion of the code to remove the dropdown menu, but adding a new filter doesn't work properly.

The following code allows you to remove a filter at a time. However, when adding a new filter, it doesn't check to see if a value currently exist.

```
$('body').on('click', '.closeselect', function(){    
    if($('.closeselect').length > 1) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        disableSelectedOption();
        $('#addmore').show();
    }
});
```

I've tried modifying the other portion where it checks the select value. Obviously it doesn't work properly.

```
$('body').on('change', '.mySelect', function(){    
    disableSelectedOption();
});
```

Comment: What is the exact issue? "but adding a new filter doesn't work properly" -- isn't an explanation, we have no idea what is "properly" for you

Comment: don't use .attr to change a property.

Comment: So add a new filter and select "Search2." Now delete the first "Search1" dropdown and add a new filter. Notice how it doesn't take into account that "Search2" has already been selected.

Comment: `this.disabled = true;` and `this.disabled = false;` are the most straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

should be

`$(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

from the [jQuery .attr manual entry](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. **To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the** `checked`, `selected`, or `disabled` state of form elements, use the
>   [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Should I change BOTH instances in the code? it's listed twice, once in the `disableSelectedOption` function and then again at the top.

Comment: Yes.  http://jsfiddle.net/Y8r4e/  works.

Comment: You're right and I apologize. I must not have refreshed my browser correctly. THANKS!!!!

Comment: It worked with `.attr()` in the OPs code :-S How this could be an answer? ;-)

Comment: you mean his originally posted code? no it didn't.

Comment: @Crayon Violent: I does in my chrome 26.0.1410.64 m. I don't see any difference in behaviour in your and his original code

Comment: @zerkms  then your chrome is magical. Or more likely, you don't understand what the problem was.

Comment: @Crayon Violent: "So add a new filter and select "Search2." Now delete the first "Search1" dropdown and add a new filter. Notice how it doesn't take into account that "Search2" has already been selected. " -- this is still reproducible with your code. Now take http://jsfiddle.net/ZTF5J/2/ and compare.

Comment: @zerkms You start with 1 dropdown and 3 values. All 3 values are selectable. You select one and add another dropdown. Only the 2 that aren't selected should now be selectable (all 3 will still show, but the one already selected will be grayed). Add another dropdown and there should only be one selectable option left.  This does not work  for the OP code. It does work for mine.

Comment: @zerkms try it over and over, it'l stop working. using .prop fixes it.

Comment: @Crayon Violent: open your example http://jsfiddle.net/Y8r4e/. Add another option, delete first, add another. Now 2 have both value `Search2`

Comment: @zerkms man..I dunno what to tell you.. /shrug

Comment: @Crayon Violent: are you kidding or what? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4486681/notananswer.png "Add another option, delete first, add another. Now 2 have both value Search2" --- isn't this algo clear enough for you to reproduce?

Comment: CrayonViolent it is as @zerkms said. It does not work. I don't know how it has been accepted.

Comment: It's working correctly for me too, i can't select the same option in two separate selects, unless i'm not understanding how you see it not working.

Comment: @zerkms Yes your instructions are simple enough...and yet i'm not reproducing it. I honestly don't know why it's working for some people and not for others..

Comment: @Crayon Violent: 1. open http://jsfiddle.net/Y8r4e/ 2. press "add another filter" 3. Click "X" after "Search1" 4. Press "add another filter". Sorry, cannot make it even simpler (reproducible in latest ff, chrome and ie9)

Comment: @Kevin B: I've made my instructions even more clear

Comment: And I don't even mention that it should be `.prop('disabled', true)`, not `$(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code, so I've rewritten it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4423c/1/):

```
$(function() {
    var $container = $('.js-selectblock'),
    nrOfOptions = $container.find('select').prop('options').length,
    $getBlocks = function() {
        return $container.children('.js-select');
    },
    $getParent = function(element) {
        return $(element).closest('.js-select');
    };

    $('#addmore').click(function() {
        var $blocks = $getBlocks();

        if ($blocks.length < nrOfOptions) {
            // restrict values on new dropdown
            var $new = $blocks.eq(0).clone();
            restrictValues($new.find('select'), getSelectedValues(), true);
            $new.appendTo($container);

            updateButtons();
        }
    }); 

    $container.on('click', '.closeselect', function() {
        if ($getBlocks().length > 1) {
            $getParent(this).remove();
            updateButtons();
        }
    });

    $container.on('change', '.mySelect', function() {
        $getBlocks().not($getParent(this)).each(function() {
            restrictValues($('select', this), getSelectedValues());
        });
    });

    function restrictValues($element, values, isnew)
    {
        var options = $element.prop('options'),
        selected = $element.prop('selectedIndex');

        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
            if (values.indexOf(options[i].value) !== -1) {
                options[i].disabled = isnew || selected != i;

                if (isnew && selected == i) {
                    ++selected;
                }
            } else {
                options[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }
        $element.prop('selectedIndex', selected);
    }

    function getSelectedValues()
    {
        var values = [];

        $getBlocks().find('select').each(function() {
            values.push($(this).val());
        });

        return values;
    }

    function updateButtons()
    {
        $('#addmore')[$getBlocks().length < nrOfOptions ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    }
});
```